# Cluster points of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where $a_1=0$, $a_{2k}=\dfrac{(-1)^k\cdot(3k^2+k)}{k^2+7}$ and $a_{2k+1}=\dfrac{k^4}{k^3+k^2+k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to find the cluster points of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and one convergent subsequence of it. I can see that in their current form, neither $a_{2k}$ nor $a_{2k+1}$ converge. So instead, can I take the positive and negative terms of $a_{2k}$ separately and call each a convergent subsequence (and so their limits a cluster point)?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated. However, I'm using Spivak as part of my course, so please don't post answers involving metric spaces or other topological concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach would give you the cluster points.

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}a_{2(2k)}=\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{3(2k)^2+(2k)}{(2k)^2+7}=3$$

I will leave the task of evaluating $\lim_{j \to \infty}a_{2(2k+1)}$ to you.